How to calculate Frame Type Value in HDLC frame?


12:34:15 Read object type AssociationLogicalName index: 2
TX:  7E A0 20 03 41 32 AB 08 E6 E6 00 C8 12 20 00 00 00 02 AB 03 CE C5 15 72 AA C6 91 9A E8 55 37 3B 9B 7E
12:34:15 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 52 CB AC E6 E7 00 CC 82 02 30 20 00 00 00 01 2A 65 23 38 32 F4 D4 51 5D 83 F4 4B C4 51 DC 1F 61 EC E8 51 DB B1 50 3B 15 29 5F 06 75 5B A5 36 A5 68 A2 72 E9 EB 35 2D 45 5B 99 CF 58 5E B2 C8 C9 DE 95 FF 97 B0 B0 6C 1B 58 EC D8 70 09 CE 83 01 A5 10 2D 05 D1 06 EC 4E 79 ED E1 48 8D 57 00 26 06 08 76 83 1D 51 86 64 7B 34 5E 95 1B EE 32 D2 6F BC E7 49 8C 96 23 2C 38 F7 AC 6A DB 48 C7 5B EA 81 06 D1 3C 7E
12:34:15 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 51 44 81 7E
12:34:15 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 54 FD C9 6A F2 9A 78 56 78 A2 3C BF 31 B8 5A 36 54 07 A0 0E 47 67 A7 4D C2 70 25 11 6A 9F C2 80 C5 4F D4 1A 30 82 28 20 C8 FE F5 24 8A 37 24 2C 72 E7 6F D1 CA EE F9 A0 82 93 84 7D D3 57 3E 15 09 93 F5 25 6E A4 B0 A5 3F 15 39 18 4A FC DA D5 3A 8D C9 99 DF 41 B8 DA 0E BE CC 4F 87 99 55 0D 76 18 5B E1 B2 C9 CE D6 63 E5 92 ED 71 52 0B A9 38 43 74 FB CB 93 8C 74 B8 53 06 D8 2C 44 04 E7 DE C7 A9 6A D9 7E
12:34:15 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 71 46 A0 7E
12:34:16 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 56 EF EA AE 2F 21 B7 37 64 64 1F 63 A7 47 E2 A7 43 7D 8A 5A AA 94 97 23 B6 3C B4 48 DB E8 F9 3A 7E AC C6 36 18 F7 D6 0A 23 94 3D F9 64 5D 05 03 2A E3 10 23 3A 92 DD 63 E6 71 24 66 AA D8 AA F2 8D C3 C0 61 76 5F F5 9E 7D DE F0 2A 68 EB F8 99 1A 10 16 80 86 A5 A7 3D F8 8A 80 09 77 7D F8 43 06 7B 1B 7A 72 32 3E BC 15 19 C9 3E EA 1C 96 B1 81 51 4A 3A 1E F2 CE 11 68 C6 34 DA 71 A0 A1 D2 07 01 0C 1E 92 7E
12:34:16 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 91 48 47 7E
12:34:16 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 58 91 03 47 74 81 6A 90 0E E2 74 FA 79 B9 0C 02 C7 54 35 FF C1 38 49 A2 DD 26 8E 81 00 9B D2 9C 86 16 F3 90 64 E4 6F 54 BB 0D 35 5E 10 C7 3B A4 EB 9F 23 EA 8D A7 FB 67 DC A5 1C 20 F7 A9 0A CB 8F 78 56 E7 2A 3B 0D A4 93 F8 51 1C 69 D5 93 42 38 93 13 E6 0F C9 38 6C 66 5A F9 D2 9E 01 2A 09 3F 3E 24 43 4E 77 72 16 B2 82 6C 04 8F 82 A8 7D 3B 8F 43 47 A3 81 0C 38 4C 7C F6 FB 54 C2 C6 49 9C 9D 0B FB 52 7E
12:34:16 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 B1 4A 66 7E
12:34:16 
RX:  7E A0 40 41 03 5A 19 B8 21 E0 7F 37 84 93 86 A7 B6 4A 9E E3 28 F4 E4 15 32 D4 37 CB B7 12 84 FF CD F6 4E 07 C0 06 17 97 E1 77 19 C6 20 52 45 C8 AE B3 D9 B7 09 D3 B1 15 4E BB C2 C6 BE B9 BD 1D 94 7E
12:34:16 
TX:  7E A0 1A 03 41 D4 CF 1A E6 E6 00 C8 0C 20 00 00 00 03 30 C7 91 F0 18 17 E1 AE FB 7E
12:34:16 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 7C B7 64 E6 E7 00 CC 82 02 46 20 00 00 00 02 63 F6 4B 43 32 80 0E C9 91 46 E1 FE AF 87 F4 36 63 73 FC 06 F7 13 5E DF 00 41 98 6E 73 95 4A 85 4C 88 97 64 F1 90 96 3C AB C2 C5 5C 9D 4F 5C 87 1F 18 49 C8 FD BA 88 59 8E 93 66 3A A8 12 C2 11 E0 D0 F3 1E 53 0E 13 B0 E1 F7 BC 3C 22 97 43 AA BE 65 61 50 04 99 69 8E 4E 38 FA FD AE B0 AB 05 9A 48 3C BE B2 7F B3 6B 9D F7 47 B5 EC 07 32 54 E8 27 7E 99 0A AC 7E
12:34:16 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 F1 4E 24 7E
12:34:16 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 7E A5 47 15 FD A9 E9 65 15 05 F1 C2 9E 97 75 C1 78 8B 41 FB 3E 45 B2 AE 7D 35 7F A6 7C B3 2C 22 4B B9 A7 D9 3E 73 90 F3 E9 48 6D 09 B0 90 FB 86 D3 CE 3D EE 5B 41 2F 7F E1 3D DC 9A CF B2 41 1F 5D C2 25 60 00 E7 87 52 C1 CE B0 2E CC 0E 94 E1 DB 35 14 F1 64 43 1E 9A 98 46 7D 87 93 F5 2F 78 1B E9 F3 AE 68 56 D8 38 0F C8 1D 22 F2 9E F4 C2 7D 5D 2E E2 E4 71 66 53 2F 49 14 77 0B E7 90 26 F7 15 44 9C 14 7E
12:34:16 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 11 40 C3 7E
12:34:17 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 70 DB AE 84 01 3A A6 E5 55 8F BA F6 98 F1 EA 4A 32 4F 5C FF B9 7E B2 58 0B 47 8E 8D 1A 79 AD 32 56 84 33 67 40 A0 1F E3 FD 8D 6F 31 67 CD 7A 9B 43 EF 15 7A 16 31 25 87 14 64 E8 47 FC 08 FB 08 DA 92 F3 C2 17 91 CE 36 54 9E A7 99 8C 55 07 35 57 DA 46 8D C9 CD A6 D1 95 25 40 1C 17 D3 8E 32 BE B0 B5 88 7A C8 F3 3F 4E 15 97 28 8A 33 FA A9 D8 B8 77 AE 7C C1 C1 2E 42 1C 49 FB FC 78 83 35 0A 98 93 5F A4 7E
12:34:17 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 31 42 E2 7E
12:34:17 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 72 C9 8D F8 18 30 80 72 2D 7F 82 DB 40 17 E1 D5 A2 B3 E6 EE 2D 28 79 BA 3E 7F CC CF 94 5D 92 E4 30 06 93 BE ED 9E 34 7C E8 F8 03 35 1E F0 24 52 33 E3 63 39 01 26 A2 3A A9 75 EC 70 A8 F7 70 D5 1E 39 9C 88 C5 5E DA 48 CB C3 F3 6F 10 1D 5E E1 94 2A 41 FF D9 BB D6 86 9E 2B B0 AF 42 08 07 CE 02 A5 8E 3B BD ED FA 48 24 A8 19 A9 60 C7 58 25 23 93 9B 4B 67 68 36 34 8B 1A 11 19 C5 DB C6 DA F5 D4 D9 13 1A 7E
12:34:17 
TX:  7E A0 07 03 41 51 44 81 7E
12:34:17 
RX:  7E A0 56 41 03 74 5E F8 8B 9A 1B 07 B8 03 50 B4 02 88 5D 40 18 4B 47 67 A0 FF B2 17 FD C5 E5 02 DD B8 18 77 ED 0D 2F FD F5 64 41 06 99 60 C2 76 A9 65 C0 12 B6 65 CD 6A 8C 57 23 95 19 30 9E 1F 50 A5 F1 89 A0 DE 9B D6 5B D0 CA ED CA C0 D1 A8 B7 C2 1D DA C5 B9 8B 7E
12:34:17 
TX:  7E A0 1A 03 41 76 D7 9C E6 E6 00 C8 0C 20 00 00 00 04 D8 9F 0B E5 CD 1E 13 91 90 7E
12:34:17 
RX:  7E A8 89 41 03 96 E3 2C E6 E7 00 CC 82 02 50 20 00 00 00 03 11 0C 2D 3F 78 64 73 0F 59 B0 3E EB DC BD 9D 00 47 06 0B 65 BA 27 4E B3 5B 58 02 43 95 85 2F 50 B9 31 E7 D0 73 BC A1 05 69 57 B5 6B 1C 2E 76 C0 3A 62 25 F3 61 2B BA 1D 7F B2 93 4F 94 59 28 64 B4 7D C9 27 27 BE C7 13 AF 2F 90 0D D5 7F 03 5C 9A FD 74 B2 04 58 8E 41 E8 8D 3A A1 C4 27 30 70 12 B9 76 F1 D1 64 7E 02 82 71 54 13 92 3E 08 27 03 D5 C2 D6 F2 1C 7E



this is data downloaded from a smart meter. I you check every 6th element in every TX, there are frame type. this is HDLC type 3 frame format. I want to learn, how to calculate this frame type? what is logic behind that?
